# Disable Basic Authentication(Spring Security) for one request and leave for all any

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

How can i disable basic authentication for one request and leave it for all any requests. 
I try do it, but these not work for mi.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/registration").permitAll()
            .and()
             .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
}
```

Basic authentication still work for "/registration".

Comment: Have you tried `http.csrf().disable().httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/registration").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()` I don't know if the order matters or not. I'm not sure.

Comment: It didn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the `/registration` is a web page which you have created. Then it should be

```
http.csrf()
    .disable()
    .httpBasic()
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/registration")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
```

You should use `HttpMethod.POST` if it is an API endpoint and not a webpage, or for some reason if you have a `POST` request for the `/registration` as well then remove the `HttpMethod.GET` all together and just leave `/registration` in the `antMatchers`

Comment: You're welcome. I would request you to accept the answer as it works.